# Infowindow for last Google Maps marker opens no matter which one clicked

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to run the google maps api in an ASP.NET MVC project, and I'm trying to add markers with info windows on every marker. Unfortunately, when I click on a marker, the info window on the last marker added opens, regardless of which marker I clicked.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
        var map;
        function initMap() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                center: { lat: 39.5, lng: -98.35 },
                zoom: 3
            });
            @foreach (var item in Model) {
                 <text>
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                      map: map,
                      position: { lat: @item.Lat, lng: @item.Lng },
                      title: '@item.Name'
                    });

                    marker.info = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        content: `<div id="content"> <h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Test</h1> <div id="bodyContent">Test </div> </div>`
                    });

                    marker.addListener('click', function () {
                        marker.info.open(map, marker);
                    });

                </text>
}
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry removed previous answer..

I just remembered I believe when I was doing my project I had to create a `createWindow(marker, content)` function and call it from the loop rather than actually creating my window inside of the loop directly

it is important that your eventlistener is created in this method also, not inside the loop

Comment: I think I may not understand how to invoke javascript functions on a razor page.


`@foreach (var item in Model) {
                 <text>
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                      map: map,
                      position: { lat: @item.Lat, lng: @item.Lng },
                      title: '@item.Name'
                    });
                    createWindow(marker)
                </text>`

It's skipping right over my createwindow function.

Comment: Update. I was in bracket hell. That worked! Thanks.

Comment: Glad :) didn't see your earlier comment else would have replied